# Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Service account object must contain a string "private_key" property

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I got this error after running npm run serve,

!!  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Service account object must contain a string "private_key" property.

Heres the screenshot of the logs

[image: Heres the screenshot of the logs]

it seems service account issue heres my initialization

`admin.initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(), });`

Comment: Have you tried just `admin.initializeApp()` instead of passing the credential property as in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-without-parameters)?

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution by commenting all of my codes , then theres new errors says , index.js not found , since im using typescript , and then i realised that im running the firebase deploy functions command using the wrong lib folder generated by typescript,

thats why i got these 2 erros:

1. Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Service account object must contain a string "private_key" property.
2. RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.